# Arithmetic expression parsing, and converting infix to postfix notation

Tags: c++, parsing, tree

I'm doing a infix to postfix conversion. The code works, but here are some points I want to improve

1) In the line of

```
while ((!operators.empty())&&(order(operators.top()) >= order(token[0])))
```

If the condition order changes ( check the stack empty later), there'll be a segmentation fault (because I'm calling operators.top() which is NULL)

2) Convert from char to string using:

```
 string s(1, operators.top());
```

which I think constantly create a new variable s and delete it.

How to improve this code?

```
#include "Parser.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

Parser::Parser()
{
    Postfix="";
    _source="";
    operators=std::stack<char>();
}

string Parser::postfix()
{
    return Postfix;
}

string Parser::source()
{
    return _source;
}

Parser& Parser::parse(string s)
{
    Postfix="";
    _source="";
    operators=std::stack<char>();

    _source=s;
    string token;

    istringstream iss (_source);
    while (iss >> token)
    {
        if (isdigit(token))
            Postfix.append(token).append(" ");

        if (isoperator(token))
        {
            if (operators.empty())
            {
                operators.push(token[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                // Pop until get the same order operator
                while ((!operators.empty())&&(order(operators.top()) >= order(token[0])))
                {
                    string s(1, operators.top());   
                    Postfix.append(s).append(" ");
                    operators.pop();
                }
                operators.push(token[0]);
            }
        }
        cout <<Postfix<<"\n";       
    }
    while(!operators.empty())
    {   
        string s(1, operators.top());   
        Postfix.append(s).append(" ");
        operators.pop();
    }
    return *this;
}

bool Parser::isdigit(const string &str)
{
    return str.find_first_not_of("-0123456789") == std::string::npos;
}

bool Parser::isoperator(const string &str)
{
    return (str=="+")||(str=="-")||(str=="*")||(str=="/");
}
int Parser::order(const char& c)
{
    if (c=='+')
        return 1;
    else if (c=='-')
        return 1;
    else if (c=='*')
        return 2;
    else if (c=='/')
        return 2;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: To improve it I would write it in a language designed for parsing. Have a look at flex and yacc(bison).

Comment: Are you trying to implement the [Shunting Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)?

Comment: yes, I'm implementing that algorithm. Rightnow is without paranthesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the condition order changes ( check the stack empty later), there'll be a segmentation fault (because I'm calling operators.top() which is NULL)

Calling top() on an empty queue is even worse then returning `NULL`. It is actually **undefined behavior**. Which means your code is broken.

This though:

```
while ((!operators.empty())&&(order(operators.top()) >= order(token[0])))
```

Is fine: The `&&` operator evaluates the left hand side first and only if this evaluation returns true will it evaluates the right hand side. So the above expression is well formed and correct.

> Convert from char to string using: which I think constantly create a new variable s and delete it.

Yes it creates a new variable `s`.

`s` will be destroyed(and its destructor called) when it goes out of scope (just like all variables are destroyed when they go out of scope). This is not a big deal.

Personally I would have used Flex/Bison to implement the parser.